# UITableView custom cell's subview contents not cleared while using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview, custom-cell

The contents of one cell is getting repeated in the next cell while scrolling. The cells are custom cells.

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"pollCell";
    IXPollCustomCell *pollCell = (IXPollCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    if (pollCell == nil) {
        pollCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXPollCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        pollCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    [self configurePollCell:pollCell atIndexPath:indexPath];//custom cell configuration
```

How to prevent subview contents from getting repeated?

EDIT:-
I'm including the configurePollCell function here.

```
-(void)configurePollCell:(IXPollCustomCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 ThreadInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 if([info.pollType isEqualToString:@"Star"])
    {
        cell.multiChoiceView.hidden=YES;
        cell.starView.hidden=NO;
        UIImage *blackStarImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"star_orange" ofType:@"png"]];
        UIImage *whiteStarImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"star_white" ofType:@"png"]];


        cell.star1ImageView.image=whiteStarImage;
        cell.star2ImageView.image=whiteStarImage;
        cell.star3ImageView.image=whiteStarImage;
        cell.star4ImageView.image=whiteStarImage;
        cell.star5ImageView.image=whiteStarImage;

        cell.selectedStar1ImageView.hidden=YES;
        cell.selectedStar2ImageView.hidden=YES;
        cell.selectedStar3ImageView.hidden=YES;
        cell.selectedStar4ImageView.hidden=YES;
        cell.selectedStar5ImageView.hidden=YES;

        cell.averageLabel.text=@"";
        //Coloring
        BOOL isStarColoringRequired=NO;
        if([info.isPollSender boolValue])
        {
            if ([info.pollScope isEqualToString:@"private"])
            {
                if([info.responseCount integerValue]>=2)
                {
                    isStarColoringRequired=YES;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                isStarColoringRequired=YES;

            }
        }
        else
        {

            if ([info.pollScope isEqualToString:@"private"])
            {
                if([info.pollVisibility isEqualToString:@"public"])
                {
                    if((info.selectedStar!=nil && [info.replied boolValue] )&&[info.responseCount integerValue]>=2)
                    {
                        isStarColoringRequired=YES;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if(info.selectedStar!=nil && [info.replied boolValue])
                {
                    isStarColoringRequired=YES;
                }
            }
        }



        if(isStarColoringRequired)
        {
            if(ansDict!=nil)
            {
                double maxHeight= cell.star1ImageView.frame.size.height;
                double maxWidth=  cell.star1ImageView.frame.size.width;

                int star1Value=[[ansDict valueForKey:@"star1"] intValue];
                int star2Value=[[ansDict valueForKey:@"star2"] intValue];
                int star3Value=[[ansDict valueForKey:@"star3"] intValue];
                int star4Value=[[ansDict valueForKey:@"star4"] intValue];
                int star5Value=[[ansDict valueForKey:@"star5"] intValue];

                NSInteger total=[info.responseCount integerValue];
                if(total!=0)
                {
                    float star1Per=(float)star1Value/total;
                    float star2Per=(float)star2Value/total;
                    float star3Per=(float)star3Value/total;
                    float star4Per=(float)star4Value/total;
                    float star5Per=(float)star5Value/total;

                    float averageScore=(star1Value+star2Value*2+star3Value*3+star4Value*4+star5Value*5)/(float)total;
                    cell.averageLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average Score - %.2f",averageScore];

                    CGFloat star1Y=maxHeight-(star1Per * maxHeight);
                    CGRect star1Rect = CGRectMake(0,star1Y,maxWidth,star1Per * maxHeight );

                    CGImageRef imageRef1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([blackStarImage CGImage], star1Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef1];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef1);
                    cell.color1ImageView.frame=star1Rect;
                    cell.color1ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.color1ImageView.image=croppedImage1;

                    CGFloat star2Y=maxHeight-(star2Per * maxHeight);
                    CGRect star2Rect = CGRectMake(0,star2Y,maxWidth,star2Per * maxHeight );
                    CGImageRef imageRef2 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([blackStarImage CGImage], star2Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef2];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef2);
                    cell.color2ImageView.frame=star2Rect;
                    cell.color2ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.color2ImageView.image=croppedImage2;

                    CGFloat star3Y=maxHeight-(star3Per * maxHeight);
                    CGRect star3Rect = CGRectMake(0,star3Y,maxWidth,star3Per * maxHeight );

                    CGImageRef imageRef3 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([blackStarImage CGImage], star3Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage3 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef3];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef3);
                    cell.color3ImageView.frame=star3Rect;
                    cell.color3ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.color3ImageView.image=croppedImage3;

                    CGFloat star4Y=maxHeight-(star4Per * maxHeight);
                    CGRect star4Rect = CGRectMake(0,star4Y,maxWidth,star4Per * maxHeight );
                    CGImageRef imageRef4 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([blackStarImage CGImage], star4Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage4 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef4];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef4);
                    cell.color4ImageView.frame=star4Rect;
                    cell.color4ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.color4ImageView.image=croppedImage4;

                    CGFloat star5Y=maxHeight-(star5Per * maxHeight);
                    CGRect star5Rect = CGRectMake(0,star5Y,maxWidth,star5Per * maxHeight );

                    CGImageRef imageRef5 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([blackStarImage CGImage], star5Rect);
                    UIImage *croppedImage5 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef5];
                    CGImageRelease(imageRef5);
                    cell.color5ImageView.frame=star5Rect;
                    cell.color5ImageView.image=nil;
                    cell.color5ImageView.image=croppedImage5;


                }

            }
        }


        int selectedStarCount=[info.selectedStar intValue];

        if([info.pollVisibility isEqualToString:@"private"])
        {

            switch (selectedStarCount) {
                case 1:
                    cell.selectedStar1ImageView.hidden=NO;

                    break;

                case 2:
                    cell.selectedStar2ImageView.hidden=NO;


                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.selectedStar3ImageView.hidden=NO;


                    break;
                case 4:
                    cell.selectedStar4ImageView.hidden=NO;


                    break;
                case 5:
                    cell.selectedStar5ImageView.hidden=NO;

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(info.selectedStar!=nil)
            {
                switch (selectedStarCount) {
                    case 1:
                        cell.selectedStar1ImageView.hidden=NO;

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        cell.selectedStar2ImageView.hidden=NO;

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cell.selectedStar3ImageView.hidden=NO;

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        cell.selectedStar4ImageView.hidden=NO;

                        break;
                    case 5:

                        cell.selectedStar5ImageView.hidden=NO;

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        if(info.image !=nil)
        {
            CGRect addFrame = cell.starView.frame;
            if (info.threadMessage.length > 100){
                addFrame.origin.y = 178 + 240;

            } else {
                addFrame.origin.y = 178 + 220;

            }

            cell.starView.frame = addFrame;
        } else {
            CGRect addFrame = cell.starView.frame;

            cell.starView.frame = CGRectMake(0,  ((0.8* self.view.frame.size.height)-10) / 2 +40, addFrame.size.width, 73);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: IXPollCustomCell *pollCell = (IXPollCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath]; May solve your problem.

Comment: We would need to see your `[self configurePollCell:pollCell atIndexPath:indexPath];`. I assume you're calling 'addSubview` there.

Comment: i have same problem. I have three different type of the cell and height is depend on the contain so i created the three different cell and used it.

Comment: @chiragshah : That is poor programming approach. Instead write a function to compute height of cell based on content.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey thanks for your opinion. next time i taken care of that thing.

Comment: @RSK : Have you selected style as 'Custom' and set identifier value 'pollCell' in Attributes Inspector of Utilities for CustomCell Xib file?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `prepareForReuse` method in your subclass and do your cleanup there. When you add a subview to a cell it stays there until you change/remove it.

`dequeueReusableCell` just gives you a cell if possible, it does not do any cleanup with the cell itself.

So if I had for example:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
        testView.tag = 20;
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:testView];
    });
}

cell.textLabel.text = @(indexPath.row).stringValue;

return cell;
```

That red subview will be present in every n-th cell as I scroll down. If I tag the view and implement the `prepareForReuse` I can remove the view.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [[self.contentView viewWithTag:20] removeFromSuperview]; //Does not crash if the view is nil. It's okay to send messages to nil in ObjC
}
```

My red view will be gone in this case as I scroll down. So the solution to your problem is that you need to add subviews once per cell init and then manage them if the cell is dequeued. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Where should I call 'prepareForReuse' function?

Comment: `prepareForReuse` gets called automatically when you call the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. You said that you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass. In that subclass implement the `- (void)prepareForReuse` method and handle the logic which takes care of preparing the cell for reuse. If you need a more detailed example feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm having many subviews in the xib. So is this the best way for me?

Comment: You don't have to remove any views just prepare the cell so that it can be reused. If you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) it says that you should hide stuff that you might or might not show. In the configure cell you show the stuff you're definitely going to show. Can you edit your question and show me what exactly is getting repeated? The code that you added in the question seems fine.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I made the contents of the subviews nil. But now I am facing a problem.Some subviews are not getting refreshed. Will hiding and unhiding the subviews refresh the content?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshed? If you want them to re-render you can call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view you want to re-render.

Comment: This is the best answer. Such a simple thing. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent subview contents from getting repeated you have to use the following method to setup your content

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Here is the place for setup
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This led to a crash :- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier pollCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Can you then register your cell within the viewDidLoad method like: self.tableView registerClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class) forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *) or nib depending on your situation. Indeed, the easiest way to do from Interface Builder